# ¿Porqué no me funciona el metodo que utilice para agregar una clase con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

espero esten teniendo un buen dia, me encuentro haciendo un modal registro en mi pagina a metodo de practica personal, y se me ocurrio la idea de hacer que cuando el registro sea creado, se oculten los input y los label del mismo registro y se muestre un mensaje de "Cuenta creada exitosamente", entonces me puse a investigar como hacerlo y aprendi sobre la clase ".className, entonces hice este sistema guiandome de uno que vi en otro post:

```
    function register(){
    console.log("Este console.log es para ver si el codigo entra a esta parte del programa, y si funciona");
    var firstStep = document.getElementsByClassName("stepOne");

    for(i=0; i<firstStep.lenght; i++){
        firstStep[i].className += "hide";
    }
}
```

El problema es que no funciona, y no se porque, la clase esta bien creada, ya probe agregarla manualmente y funciona bien, la clase es:

```
.hide{
  display: none;
}
```

Y el modal es el siguiente:

```
    <div class="modal-register modal fade" id="register" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="stepOne exampleModalLabel">Registro</h5>
          <h5 id="stepTwo" class="hide">Registro existoso</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <p class="error-message"></p>
              <p class="hide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum, libero. Porro, sint optio! Laboriosam asperiores, quam quasi eius, natus consequuntur porro minima, veritatis eum molestiae nulla deserunt incidunt eveniet! Dolores aperiam deserunt quisquam, fugit dolorem perspiciatis eos consequuntur totam repellendus veniam quas corrupti, alias cum?</p>
              <label  for="message-text" class="stepOne col-form-label">Nombre Completo</label>
              <input  id="name" type="text" class="stepOne form-control">
              <label  for="message-text" class="step Onecol-form-label">Correo Electronico</label>
              <input  id="email" type="text" class="stepOne form-control" >
              <label  for="message-text"  class=" stepOne col-form-label">Contraseña</label>
              <input  id="pass" type="password" class="stepOne form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="cerrar()" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
          <button id="buttonContinue" type="button" onclick="register()" class="btn btn-primary">Continuar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Cabe destacar que esta hecho con bootstrap,
Muchas gracias!
Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias como siempre Benito, voy a probarlo

Comment: Una pregunta, puedo agregarle otro class, es decir:

Comment: <input class="stepOne" id="pass" type="password" class="form-control">

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, solo tenia la duda de ver si podia funcionar, pero ya vi que no!

Comment: No me funciona @Benito-B, actualizare el post con los cambios

Comment: Quieres que en el mismo modal aparezca un mensaje, o en algun tipo de mensaje flotante tipo [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)?

Comment: Hola. Te puse una respuesta usando **className**. Lo que tratabas de hacer tenía un pequeño defecto de interpretación del atributo y por ello fallaba.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En vez de varios comentarios, te dejo mejor una respuesta entera:

El error principal está en la manera de acceder a las clases de los elementos, ya que estas forman una lista (accesible en el atributo `classList`. La manera más correcta sería:

```js
// Accedo a todos los elementos de clase "texto"
const textos = document.getElementsByClassName("texto"); 
for (let i = 0; i < textos.length; i++) { // Recorro el array
  textos[i].classList.add("red");  /* Para cada elemento, accedo a su lista de clases
 y le añado la clase "red", que hará que se vean en rojo */
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="texto">Soy un texto</p>
<p class="texto">Soy un texto</p>
<p class="texto">Soy un texto</p>
```

Espero que este breve ejemplo te sirva, cualquier duda aquí estamos.

Comment: Hice la modificacion de ClassName a ClassList, pero todavia no me funciona

Answer (score 2):

El código que te ofrece @Benito-B es perfecto. No obstante, como estás tratando de usar **className** te voy a plantear una sugerencia:
El atributo className **es una cadena de texto**. De modo que si le agregas **"hide"** creas como nombre de clase **"stepOnehide"** debes hacer la adición con un espacio así **" hide"**.
Muestro un código de prueba.

```js
function register(){
    var firstStep = document.getElementsByClassName("stepOne");
    firstStep[0].className += " hide";
}
```

```css
.hide{ display: none; }
```

```html
<div onclick="register()" class="stepOne">
<p>Haga click aquí para ocultar el texto</p>
</div>
```

Este mecanismo tiene un problema: si la clase ya hubiese sido agregada se genera una doble asignación.
Espero te sirva para aclarar la duda. Porque el código de @Benito-B **es el correcto**. El mio es para que opere lo que tratabas de hacer, con el recurso que usabas.

Comment: Efectivamente, se puede usar de esa manera, pero luego a la hora de *eliminar* una clase, usar `className` es un rollo! Por eso intento evitar el uso de `className` siempre que puedo. Siempre hay excepciones claro, por ejemplo, cuando tienes una clase `element` y otras derivadas como `element--white` y `element--black`, en ese caso, y siempre que no vaya a necesitar aplicar otras clases a esos elementos, sí usaría `className` para concatenarle la variación que necesite en el momento. Excelente aporte de todas maneras

Comment: Gracias por el comentario @Benito-B. Justamente por eso insistí en que **tu respuesta es el camino correcto** mientras que la mía es apenas una sugerencia para ayudar a entender el atributo className